# Create new column with values indexed from another table

Tags: r, indexing, lookup

I have two tables:

table1:

```
Var1   Var2
01-01  dhold_1
01-01  dhold_2
01-01  dhold_3
02-01  dhold_1
02-01  dhold_2
03-01  dhold_3
```

table2:

```
md      dhold_1   dhold_2   dhold_3
01-01   1.01      1.05      1.04
02-01   1.03      0.09      0.99
```

I would like to create a new column in table1, let's call it `Var3`.
The new column should contain the corresponding value from table 2. I think you know what I mean when looking at how the end result should be:

table1 after adding the new column (Goal):

```
Var1   Var2      Var3
01-01  dhold_1   1.01
01-01  dhold_2   1.05
01-01  dhold_3   1.04
02-01  dhold_1   1.03
02-01  dhold_2   0.09
03-01  dhold_3   0.99
```

I tried the following in R:

```
table1$Var3 <- table2[match(table1$Var1,table2$md),match(table1$Var2,colnames(table2))]
```

The code above produces to some sort the output I wanted, put creates not only 1 new column, but `n` new columns, each containing the same. Given that I have a larger file it ends up in a `vector allocation error`.

I spent hours looking for a solution. Anyone having an idea? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get `table2` in long format and then join.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

table2 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -md) %>%
  right_join(table1, by = c('md' = 'Var1', 'name' = 'Var2'))

#   md    name    value
#  <chr> <chr>   <dbl>
#1 01-01 dhold_1  1.01
#2 01-01 dhold_2  1.05
#3 01-01 dhold_3  1.04
#4 02-01 dhold_1  1.03
#5 02-01 dhold_2  0.09
#6 02-01 dhold_3  0.99
```

**data**

I think `table1`'s last value should be `02-01` ? I corrected that and used it in data.

```
table1 <- structure(list(Var1 = c("01-01", "01-01", "01-01", "02-01", "02-01", 
"02-01"), Var2 = c("dhold_1", "dhold_2", "dhold_3", "dhold_1", 
"dhold_2", "dhold_3")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

table2 <- structure(list(md = c("01-01", "02-01"), dhold_1 = c(1.01, 1.03
), dhold_2 = c(1.05, 0.09), dhold_3 = c(1.04, 0.99)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```